# How to multiply 2 object data types in python?

Tags: python, pycharm

This is from Udemy bootcamp course (Day 76).

I am a newbie in Python. So, apologize if I cannot frame my question correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. I have an excel sheet where there are several columns and the datatypes of each column are as shown below.  Line 8 is giving me an error in Pycharm by saying I cannot multiply. My excel sheet : apps.csv has 10 columns. Please see attached picture.
[apps.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co3Gy.png)

```
App                object
Category           object
Rating            float64
Reviews             int64
Size_MBs          float64
Installs           object
Type               object
Price              object
Content_Rating     object
Genres             object
dtype: object
```

I want to multiply the "Price" and "Install" columns from excel sheet as shown below and add a new column named 'Revenue Estimate' :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('apps.csv')
clean_df=df.dropna()
clean_df.loc[:, "Installs"] = clean_df.loc[:, "Installs"].astype(str).str.replace(",", "")
clean_df.loc[:, "Installs"] = pd.to_numeric(clean_df.loc[:, "Installs"])
clean_df.loc[:,"Price"] = clean_df.loc[:,"Price"].astype(str).str.replace('$', "")
clean_df.loc[:, "Price"] = pd.to_numeric(clean_df.loc[:,"Price"])
#Line 8:  
clean_df['Revenue_Estimate']= clean_df.Installs * clean_df.Price
```

Error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
 clean_df['Revenue_Estimate']= clean_df.Installs * clean_df.Price
```

=============

I tried  this as well. did not work

```
 df_apps_clean['Revenue_Estimate'] = df_apps_clean.Installs.mul(df_apps_clean.Price)
```

Error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
clean_df['Revenue_Estimate'] = clean_df.Installs.mul(clean_df.Price)
```

Comment: Look at your question. Do you notice that the formatting makes it hard to understand your question? For example, it looks like the two lines beginning `#Line 8:` should be part of the preceding literal block. Similarly, you should format the error messages as literal blocks (i.e., bracketed by triple backquotes). And what the heck is the final "clean_df['Revenue_Estimate']..." line meant to tell us? I can't make sense of your question so will ignore it. Pretty much everyone reading your question will respond the same way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 8 to:

```py
clean_df.insert(10, "Revenue Estimate", clean_df.loc[:, "Price"] * clean_df.loc[:, "Installs"], True)
```

Where 10 corresponds to the column which I want to add under the name "Revenue Estimate" .

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('apps.csv')
clean_df = df.dropna()

clean_df['Installs'] = clean_df['Installs'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
clean_df['Price'] = clean_df['Price'].str.replace('$', '').astype(float)

clean_df['Revenue_Estimate'] = clean_df['Installs'] * clean_df['Price']
```

Try to convert Installs into integer and Price to float, it may work for you.

Please give some more clarity if it doesn't work for you..

Comment: Sorry it does not work.

Comment: still you get the same error or any other?

Comment: The error message is as follows :  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  clean_df['Revenue_Estimate'] = clean_df['Installs']*(clean_df['Price'])